# MVC can't find dependency after publish

Tags: .net, iis, visual-studio-2015, publish

I am trying to publish a MVC app from VS2015.

I do the publish successfully but when I try to run the app I get

```
Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

If I enable "enable 32 bit application" on remote IIS I get :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'xxx' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

I usually get this error when I build a 64 bit dll on 32 bit or the other way around. This is not the case here. There are 64 bit dll's build on 64 bit.

What should I do ?

P.S: I also tried to get the 32 bit DLL, build  on 32 bit and deploy it to IIS with "enable 32 bit application" set to true and I get the same error

Comment: Looks like its not 64/32 bit issue but missing dependency. You shouldn't enable "enable 32 bit application".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

That particular dll needed C++ Redistributable 2010. Installed it on server and it works.